# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_setter' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I've been trying to get datatables working but don't see what I am missing in my setup.  I've spent a good chunk of time tinkering and googling and am hoping this is something simeple I'm missing that someone here might be able to spot.

Thanks in advance.

Error Message:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_setter' of undefined
at cellProcess (jquery.dataTables.js:1607)
at _fnGetRowElements (jquery.dataTables.js:1628)
at HTMLTableElement.<anonymous> (jquery.dataTables.js:6419)
at Function.each (jquery-2.2.3.min.js:2)
at n.fn.init.each (jquery-2.2.3.min.js:2)
at n.fn.init.DataTable [as dataTable] (jquery.dataTables.js:6092)
at n.fn.init.$.fn.DataTable (jquery.dataTables.js:14775)
at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> ((index):573)
at i (jquery-2.2.3.min.js:2)
at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-2.2.3.min.js:2)
```

My JS:

```
  <script>
  $(function() {
      $("#people").DataTable({
        "iDisplayLength": 25,
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": 'http://example.com/datatables-people',
        "columns": [
          { data: 'firstname', defaultContent: '' },
          { data: 'lastname', defaultContent: '' },
          { data: 'userid', defaultContent: '' },
          { data: 'title', defaultContent: '' },
          { data: 'FK_department', defaultContent: '' },
          { data: 'pagerid', defaultContent: '' },
          { data: 'FK_authcode', defaultContent: '' },
          { data: 'roomnumber', defaultContent: '' },
          { data: 'pubroomnumber', defaultContent: '' }
        ]
      });
  });
</script>
```

A couple sample columns of the table:

```
      <table id="people" class="table table-bordered table-striped dataTable">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Given Name</th>
        <th>Surname</th>
        <th>Extension</th>
        <th>PDM ID</th>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Department</th>
        <th>Pager</th>
        <th>Authcode</th>
        <th>Room Number</th>
        <th>Pub Room Number</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
                  <tr>
          <td>Sample</td>
          <td>Person</td>
          <td>Ext</td>
          <td>512304</td>
          <td>Physiotherapist</td>
          <td>Physiotherapy</td>
          <td>13780</td>
          <td>0</td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
                  <tr>
          <td>Sample</td>
          <td>Person</td>
          <td>Ext</td>
          <td>518435</td>
          <td>Staffing Clerk</td>
          <td>Customer Support Centre</td>
          <td>0</td>
          <td>0</td>
          <td>E1-501</td>
          <td>E1-501</td>
        </tr>
                  <tr>
          <td>Sample</td>
          <td>Person</td>
          <td>Ext</td>
          <td>523385</td>
          <td>Coordinator</td>
          <td>Birthing Centre</td>
          <td>15288</td>
          <td>0</td>
          <td>B4-125</td>
          <td>B4-125</td>
        </tr> ....
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
You have missed a column for Extension

 <script>
  $(function() {
      $("#people").DataTable({
        "iDisplayLength": 25,
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": 'http://example.com/datatables-people',
        "columns": [
          { data: 'firstname', defaultContent: '' },
          { data: 'lastname', defaultContent: '' },
          { data: 'extension', defaultContent: '' },
          { data: 'userid', defaultContent: '' },
          { data: 'title', defaultContent: '' },
          { data: 'FK_department', defaultContent: '' },
          { data: 'pagerid', defaultContent: '' },
          { data: 'FK_authcode', defaultContent: '' },
          { data: 'roomnumber', defaultContent: '' },
          { data: 'pubroomnumber', defaultContent: '' }
        ]
      });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you... sometimes can't see for the forest for the trees.